# Change in potential energy after infinitesimal variation in position

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, potential-energy, variational-calculus

The a particle with the potential $V(x^2+y^2)$ undergoes an active transformation where

$x\rightarrow x+y\delta$

$y\rightarrow y-x\delta$

The exercise was to prove that the Lagrangian of the system remains the same even after the transformation, but I don't understand how the potential energy remains the same.

A solution I found did it this way:

$V(x^2+y^2)\rightarrow V(x^2+y^2)+\delta V(x^2+y^2)$

$=V(x^2+y^2)+\frac{\partial V(x^2+y^2)}{\partial x}\delta x+\frac{\partial V(x^2+y^2)}{\partial y}\delta y$

$=V(x^2+y^2) + 2x\delta x + 2y\delta y$

... (I understand the rest, it's just these steps I'm confused about)

- How is the first step right? wouldn't it need to be $V(x^2+y^2)\rightarrow V((x+y\delta)^2+(y+x\delta)^2)$
- And why would $\frac{\partial V(x^2+y^2)}{\partial x} = 2x\delta x$? Why is the chain rule not followed here where we would also need to add $V'(x^2+y^2)$?

Comment: do you mean $x\to x+\delta y$ rather than $y\delta$?  What is $y\delta$?

Comment: $y\delta$ is an infinitesimal parameter that is proportional to the $y$ coordinate. That is how my book says it, so that's how I learned it. Is $\delta y$ more conventional?

Comment: yes I think it more conventional to think of $\delta y$ as an infinitesimal change in $y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like:

$$ (x+y\delta)^2 + (y-x\delta)^2 = (x^2 + 2xy\delta + y^2\delta^2) + (y^2-2xy\delta +x^2\delta^2)$$
$$ = (x^2 + y^2) + 2(xy-xy)\delta + (y^2-x^2)\delta^2 $$
$$ = (x^2 + y^2) + (y^2-x^2)\delta^2 $$

keeping only 1st order in $\delta$:

$$ (x+y\delta)^2 + (y-x\delta)^2 = (x^2 + y^2)$$